# How to meet python3 dependency with existing python?

Tags: 18.04, python, dependencies

I installed python3.7 on Ubuntu18.04, and made it my "python3". But when I install some package with python3 as dependency, it will specifically download and install python3.6.9. Is it possible to avoid that? I want to use the package with python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

You can eventually change this, but its going to lead to a lot of pain. I'd recommend using a virtualenv rather than trying to change the system defaults:

```
python3.7 -m venv myvirtualenv
cd myvirtualenv
source ./bin/activate
```

you can now use pip to install whatever you need, and it will be installed in this separate environment. When you need to run the app, just source bin/activate again.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I have to go through a lot of pain too: install all the python3-* packages manually with pip (and at least some have to be in the correct version), and unless pip in a venv is somehow smarter than "normal" pip, it will fail to build some of those as the Python.h headers are only in the 3.6 folder, even after installing libpython3.7-dev, and the only workaround for THAT so far is to sym-link to the include folder of 3.6 which.. well.. is clearly not a good solution. But I take your answer as a "no"?

Comment: Yes, i wouldn't, i dont think you need to install any python3-* packages (these are OS packages), just pip install the libs you need and it will pull the deps it needs - pip freeze and pip -r can help installing libs as well.